# How to extract values in new "builtin.datetimeV2.timerange" (start , end) time of LUIS Json string in botframework

Tags: c#, .net, json, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using botframework (Bot builder v3.8.x) in c# to build my bot and I want to access the values of value, start and end time keys in LUIS new datetimeV2 entities.

In following JSON I want to extract **"value": "2017-07-04"**, **"start": "16:00:00"** & **"end": "18:00:00"**

```
{
  "entity": "july 4th",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
  "startIndex": 58,
  "endIndex": 65,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "XXXX-07-04",
        "type": "date",
        "value": "2016-07-04"
      },
      {
        "timex": "XXXX-07-04",
        "type": "date",
        "value": "2017-07-04"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "entity": "from 4 pm to 6 pm",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.timerange",
  "startIndex": 67,
  "endIndex": 84,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "(T16,T18,PT2H)",
        "type": "timerange",
        "start": "16:00:00",
        "end": "18:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am tring to do following but it gives Null Reference Exception

```
        private const string DateEntityType = "builtin.datetimeV2.date";
        private const string TimeRangeEntityType = "builtin.datetimeV2.timerange";
        var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);
        foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
        {

            switch (entity.Type)
            {
                case DateEntityType:
                    var date = entity.Resolution.Values.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("value").ToString() ?? null;
                    break;
                case TimeRangeEntityType:
                    var startTime = entity.Resolution.Values.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("start").ToString() ?? null;
                    var endTime = entity.Resolution.Values.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("end").ToString() ?? null;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

What is the easiest way to get those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for sure not the elegantest way, but I managed to get the data out of the structure by a litte help from Newtonsoft:

```
if (entity.Type == "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange")
{
    foreach (var vals in entity.Resolution.Values)
    {
        if (((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)vals).First.SelectToken("type").ToString() == "daterange")
        {
            start = (DateTime)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)vals).First.SelectToken("start");
            end = (DateTime)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)vals).First.SelectToken("end");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Patrick B. Are you using builtin LuisResult class. It is giving me following error whenever it detects a datetime enity in entieties:
**Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is not marked as serializable.**

Comment: I recently upgraded my bot app to bot sdk 3.8 due to issues with Luis. I'd suggest to upgrade to the latest sdk as well. Now the bot app is using Newtonsoft 10.0.2

Comment: I am using bot framework version 3.8 and Newtonsoft 10.0.2 and it still gives me the same exception. Are you using **LuisResult** to handle json from LUIS ?

Comment: I have finally figured out the answer to that exception. It was being thrown because i was passing **result.Entities** directly into the **EntityRecommendation** list and since SDK does not have support for updated protocol of LUIS so it couldn't properly serialize it. Fix would be using this 
**var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>();**
istead of this 
**var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);**

Answer (score 1):

Same as Patrik B, but using JObject from Newtonsoft.

```
        case TimeRangeEntityType:
                object jsonstring;
                entity.Resolution.TryGetValue("values", out jsonstring);

                //Remove the first and last characters so that we get a proper json string
                var WellformedJson = jsonstring.ToString().Substring(1, jsonstring.ToString().Length - 2);
                JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(WellformedJson);
                var startTime = (DateTime)jobj["start"];
                var endTime = (DateTime)jobj["end"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used json2csharp to create create a model for LuisResult.

```
    public class TopScoringIntent
{
    public string intent { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class Intent
{
    public string intent { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string timex { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
}

public class Resolution
{
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string entity { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int startIndex { get; set; }
    public int endIndex { get; set; }
    public Resolution resolution { get; set; }
}

public class LuisResultModel
{
    public string query { get; set; }
    public TopScoringIntent topScoringIntent { get; set; }
    public List<Intent> intents { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> entities { get; set; }
}
```

Then I serialize the LuisResult to json before deserializing it into my new model:

```
var t = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(luisResult);
_luisResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LuisResultModel>(t);
```

where    _luisResult is of type    LuisResultModel. This being a strongly typed object I can now do this.

```
var startDate = _luisResult.Entity.First().resolution.values.First().start;
var endDate = _luisResult.Entity.First().resolution.values.First().end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing some thing generic? I donot like so many ifs.

```
public static V GenericLuisEntityResolution<V>(EntityRecommendation entity)
        {
            dynamic result = null;

            if (entity.Resolution == null)
            {
                result = entity.Entity;
            } else
            {
                dynamic value = entity.Resolution.FirstOrDefault().Value;
                result = value[0];
            }

            return result;
        }

 Dictionary<string,dynamic> date = GenericLuisEntityResolution<dynamic>(yourdata...);
  date ["start"].....
```